# ggplotly get data values of clicks

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

How can I get the x and y coordinates of an interactive map created with ggplot and plotly in R shiny? I want to get the x axis values and based on that display other data. Here is some dummy code.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(

       plotlyOutput("distPlot")
    
 )


server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    gg1 = iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(gg1)
    })
}

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what your are looking for. The plotly package offers a function `event_data()` to get e.g. the coordinates of click events inside of a shiny app. See [here](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#shiny-plotly-inputs). If you have multiple plots you could use the `source` argument to set an id and to get the event data for a specific plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  plotlyOutput("distPlot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    gg1 = iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(gg1, source = "Plot1")
  })
  
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "Plot1")
    
    if (is.null(d)) {
      "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)"
    } else {
      x <- round(d$x, 2)
      y <- round(d$y, 2)
      cat("[", x, ", ", y, "]", sep = "")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: when I have more than one plotly plots, how can I give some id so that to refer to the one clicked?

Comment: You can set an id via the `source` argument in `plot_ly` or `ggplotly` and call the events for a specific plot via the `source` argument of `event_data`. See my edit.